# Add the time remaining until the end of the year to today's date

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I want to filter a data frame using a `date` column. The code yould return only the rows with a `date` less than today's date + time until the year's end.

I tried the following:

```
df2=df[df['date'] < dt.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')+pd.tseries.offsets.YearEnd]
```

Comment: Is this different than simply being date < 12-31-2022?

Comment: I want it automatically. I dont want to change the date in the code each year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be turning your datetimes into strings. Also, you forgot to instantiate `YearEnd`.

The following will give you the year end, using today's year:

```py
year_end = pd.Timestamp.utcnow().date() + pd.offsets.YearEnd()
```

You should then be able to use that for filtering, i.e.:

```py
df[df['date'] <= year_end]
```